# Converting projection type into lonlat gridtype with CDO in Ubuntu

Tags: netcdf, ubuntu, climate-data-operators

I have an issue with the grids, I am using EUR-11 domain, rotated coordinates and I would like to convert them in lonlat so that I can cut the netCDF file into my study area, where I also have lonlat coordinates.

```
gridtype  = projection
gridsize  = 174688
xsize     = 424
ysize     = 412
xname     = rlon
xlongname = "longitude in rotated pole grid"
xunits    = "degrees"
yname     = rlat
ylongname = "latitude in rotated pole grid"
yunits    = "degrees"
xfirst    = -28.375
xinc      = 0.110000001623275
yfirst    = -23.375
yinc      = 0.10999999777244
scanningMode = 64
grid_mapping = rotated_latitude_longitude
grid_mapping_name = rotated_latitude_longitude
grid_north_pole_latitude = 39.25
grid_north_pole_longitude = -162.
north_pole_grid_longitude = 0.es.
```

I already tried several options but I am not sure if they worked. Can someone help?

Comment: I then tried this code cdo griddes infile.nc > mygrid
sed -i "s/generic/lonlat/g" mygrid  and then cdo setgrid,mygrid infile.nc infile_fixedgrid.nc apparently it worked but if I now check my new netcdf file cutted to the study area, the gridtype now is curvilinear.